# Upgrading from BIRT 2.5.2 to 3.7.1

Tags: war, birt

We previously used the code below to set up BIRT Engine to use within our servlet, the migration guide says you just need to add the BIRT jars to the classpath, the BIRT jars were added to WEB-INF\lib.

When we run the app now, `IReportEngineFactory` returns null. Any help is appreciated.

```
public static synchronized IReportEngine getBirtEngine(ServletContext sc) throws Exception {

    EngineConfig config  = new EngineConfig();
    config.setBIRTHome("");


    config.setLogConfig("C:/Temp", Level.FINEST);
    config.setLogFile("birtLog.log");
    realPath = sc.getRealPath("/reports");
    log.info("Server Info:  " + sc.getServerInfo());
    log.info(" Servlet Context Name:  " + sc.getServletContextName());
    log.info("Real Path:  " + realPath);
    log.info("#####Creating new Birt Engine#####");
    //log.info("Birt Home is: " + config.getBIRTHome());
    IPlatformContext context = new PlatformServletContext(sc);
    config.setPlatformContext(context);
    try {
        Platform.startup(config);
        //log.info("Birt Home is: " + config.getPlatformContext().toString());
        IReportEngineFactory factory =  (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject
                (IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
        birtEngine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        throw e;
    }

    return birtEngine;
}
```

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem.
While upgrading from BIRT 2.5.2 to BIRT 3.7.1. Have you solved this problem? Thanx in advance, Nele

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line solved the problem in my custom BirtEngine.java configuration:

```
IPlatformContext context = new PlatformServletContext(sc);
config.getAppContext().put(EngineConstants.WEBAPP_CLASSPATH_KEY, "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, we had not yet solved the problem.I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

On many posts in the net I read you must not set BIRT home and platform context anymore. So your code should become something like this:

```
public static synchronized IReportEngine getBirtEngine() throws Exception {

    EngineConfig config  = new EngineConfig();
    config.setLogConfig("C:/Temp", Level.FINEST);
    config.setLogFile("birtLog.log");

    try {
        Platform.startup(config);
        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject
                (IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
        birtEngine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        throw e;
    }

    return birtEngine;
}
```